# Rendering images in Twig

Tags: image, twig, symfony

I have a form which takes Image (png file type) and saves it's name in the database. The image is uploaded to `web/uploads/Images/` directory, my question is, how do I render this image in my Twig template? This is what I have so far:

```
<div class=products>
    {% for key,product in products  %}
      <div class="product-{{ key }}">
        <div class="p-name"> {{ product.name }}</div>
        <div class="p-price"> {{ product.price }}</div>
        <div class="p-description"> {{ product.description }}</div>
        <div class="p-image">
          <img src="{{ asset('uploads/Images/' ~ product.Image) }}"></img>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And this is what I have in [DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr75b.png)

I am completely new to Symfony, so please bear with me.

EDIT: The path to the image is wrong, how should it be written?

Comment: As per @gp_sflover has commented on my answer, if it's just a type, it's better to close this question. Please let us know. If it's not a type (I mean "scr"), then we'll need more info, since the code looks ok (I have something similar).

Comment: @AlvinBunk I left a comment under an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your `img` tag you have the spelling of "src" incorrect. Should be like so:

```
<img src="{{ asset('uploads/Images/' ~ product.Image) }}"></img>
```

Maybe that's the problem? Otherwise, it looks correct.

Comment: IMHO this was better as a comment because if this was the real problem (like it seems) it's better to encourage the OP to close his question due to the uselessness of the same in relation with stated in the title (SO encourage to close questions related to simple user typos or coding error like here). PS: I don't want to be controversial with you, it's only because SO is full of useless post that slowing down good research keys :-).

Comment: @gp_sflover

Oh god It is such a stupid mistake I am sorry for including it here, but sadly this does not solve my issue, the file is still could not be loaded. As mentioned, my file is in project's root/web/includes/Images. 

Also if I try to follow this route to see my image from browser I get "No route found" error.

Maybe this has to do something with my apache config or my files are not public? Can I get a link for an article on how to make sure these are okay? Or just a general explanation if it is not hard to do.

Comment: Can you post the current error of your image not found (where does it search your picture), and the path wher the picture is?
Just above, you mentionned `web/includes/Images` and your twig go into `web/uploads/Images`. Also, try to avoid caps latter in your folder or filename

Comment: Hi notrealme. When you view your page rendering this twig file in FireFox and select "Inspect Element", what does the `img` tag show for a path? Also, you should be able to enter the full URL to the image path in your browser and see the image in your browser --> If that doesn't work, it's probably an Apache config issue.

Comment: Hello @AlvinBunk and thank you for helping me. This is what I see in DOM. `<img src="/uploads/Images/bcfe077ec3683ab178ae0511c1e6dfe5.png" style="width:200px; height:200px;">` and if I try to folllow this route: `/uploads/Images/bcfe077ec3683ab178ae0511c1e6dfe5.png` I get Symfony error: `No route found, for GET ..... ` I would be really thankful if you could point me to the article which could solve my apache config issues.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there are images in the `web/uploads/Images` folder? I would do a `ls -al` to verify you have images in that path.